# useEffect creates an infinite loop but I dont understand it completely

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have had in the past similar problems of infinite recursion, but I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.
Here you can have the important parts of my function
I have these states on top

```
  const PREV_ICON = <span aria-hidden="true" className="carousel-control-prev-icon" />;
  const NEXT_ICON = <span aria-hidden="true" className="carousel-control-next-icon" />;
  const [control, setControl] = useState({ prev: null, next: null });
```

So basically the `NEXT_ICON` is a constant declared on top.
If I have more than 4 items on my carousel I want to show the next icon

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSkills = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await skillsInformationService.getSkills(sessionUserInfo.jigsawId);
        setSkillGroups(result);
        const slices = _(result).keys().chunk(4).value();
        setGroupSlices(slices);
        setLoading(false);
        setControl({
          prev: null,
          next: (_(result).size() < 4) ? null : NEXT_ICON
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setSkillGroups([]);
        setGroupSlices([]);
      }
    };
    fetchSkills();
  }, [sessionUserInfo.jigsawId, NEXT_ICON]);
```

`VSCode` added by default the `NEXT_ICON` to the array of params of `useEffect`, I didn't realize until I saw that `useEffect` kept on being called.
So then I delete `NEXT_ICON` and it was only being called once, but if I do that the `setControl({})` seems to not be called.
But I might have misunderstood the use of `useEffect`, why is `useEffect` being called if `NEXT_ICON` is a constant that doesn't change.  And I think that if I want to use a variable inside `useEffect` I have to call it the params right.  So I do need to put `NEXT_ICON`  next to `sessionUserInfo.jigsawId`, otherwise it is `null`? Right?

Comment: Instead of saving the controls in state you can compute them in render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a constant in the block it is defined. Since the block in your case is the functional component, each time you re-render the component the function is re-run, and thus you create a new `PREV_ICON`,`NEXT_ICON`, and the `useEffect` will be executed.

The solution is to move the two constants outside of the function.

```js
const PREV_ICON = <span aria-hidden="true" className="carousel-control-prev-icon" />;
const NEXT_ICON = <span aria-hidden="true" className="carousel-control-next-icon" />;
  
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [control, setControl] = useState({ prev: null, next: null });
  
  ....
  
  
  useEffect( ... ,[sessionUserInfo.jigsawId, NEXT_ICON]); // whether you have NEXT_ICON here, or not, now makes no difference.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having an infinite loop because the identities of objects stored in your constants `PREV_ICON` and `NEXT_ICON` change for every single render (as soon as you're using functional component) and while having `NEXT_ICON` as a dependency for `useEffect` hook - you're just basically having a new object every time (which changes for every render).

Also storing the whole components (like `PREV_ICON` and `NEXT_ICON`) to the internal state of the object might not be the best decision.

Possible options to fix this situation:

1. You can consider changing the kind of data to store in the component state. For example instead of components you can use booleans like `PREV_ICON_VISIBLE`, `NEXT_ICON_VISIBLE` and based on their values later render whatever content you want.
2. You can extract `PREV_ICON` and `NEXT_ICON` out of your functional component.
3. You can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hooks to preserve identities of `PREV_ICON` and `NEXT_ICON` (which might not be the most elegant way).